# (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB conexión con base de datos local en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql, vb.net

Estoy practicando en base al libro Beginning Visual Basic 2015 de Wrox

En el capítulo 13 muestra como conectar con la base de datos pubs usando Microsoft SQL Server 2014

El código completo está en:

http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/16/11190921/DOWNLOAD/092117%20C13.zip

pero la parte importante es la cadena de conexión:

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection("server=localhost\SQLExpress;database=pubs;user id=sa;password=SQL2014wrox")
```

El ejercicio funciona correctamente.

Ahora bien, me interesa poder conectar usando LocalDB para crear más adelante una aplicación con base de datos embebida o portable.

Tengo la base de datos pubsFedeteka que es una copia de pubs para hacer la prueba

Si en VisualStudio voy a Tools - Connect to Database y utilizo
(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB 
aparecen las bases de datos, selecciono pubsFedeteka y la prueba de conexión es exitosa

Sin embargo no puedo replicar el ejercicio estableciendo la conexión por código.

En mi caso cambio

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection("server=localhost\SQLExpress;database=pubs;user id=sa;password=SQL2014wrox")
```

por

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True ;AttachDbFileName=pubsFedeteka")
```

y si bien al correr el programa no me da error de conexión el DataGrid no presenta ningún dato.

Leí lo que pude en Internet y el algunos casos recomendaban usan \ en lugar de \, o agregar @ a la cadena de conexión pero no he tenido suerte.

Alguna orientación de que puede estar faltando?

O debo agregar la base de datos local pubsFedeteka como recurso al proyecto?

Answer (score 1):

**>>Ahora bien, me interesa poder conectar usando LocalDB para crear más adelante una aplicación con base de datos embebida o portable.**

Pero si usas Sql server no vas a poder ser ni embebida ni portable ya que requieres del servicio de Sql Server ejecutando en la pc del usuario

Si necesitas algo que cumpla estas caracteristicas deberias apunta a Sql Compact o [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

**>>Sin embargo no puedo replicar el ejercicio estableciendo la conexión por código.**

Si la db esta integrada al servicio de Sql Server deberias usar

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection("server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=pubs;user id=sa;password=SQL2014wrox")
```

o sea defiens el nombre de la db

Ademas la definicion del AttachDbFileName es incorrecta

```
AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\pubsFedeteka
```

**>>si bien al correr el programa no me da error de conexión el DataGrid no presenta ningún dato.**

Si el archivos .mdf esta adjunto al proyecto deberias validar que base se esta copiando al \bin\Debug tiene registros que mostrar.

Tambien puede ser que la consulta que ejecutes hayas definido un `WHERE` que filtre los registros y no devuelva registros.

**>>debo agregar la base de datos local pubsFedeteka como recurso al proyecto?**

Como recurso NO ya que no sera un archivo embebido dentro del .exe, pero si deberias integrar el .mdf dentro del proyecto

Comment: Hola Leandro muy amable por tu respuesta. Entonces tengo una confusión con respecto a esto: msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx " Cuando se realiza la conexión, se crea y se inicia automáticamente la infraestructura de SQL Server necesaria, permitiendo que la aplicación use la base de datos sin tareas de configuración complejas o prolongadas en el tiempo" Es decir, yo pensaba que una vez configurada de esa forma entonces permitía que el paquete instalador con su base de datos ya fueran suficientes y no se precisara instalar un servidor de base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a probar lo que sugieres e investigar tema SQLite aunque vi que las bases de datos no están encriptadas ni se pueden encriptar sin una extensión de terceros.

Answer (score 1):

1. Comprobar si LocalDB está instalado.

   ```
   string FileName = "SqlLocalDB.exe";
   string command = "\"" + FileName + " \"";
   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(command, " i ");
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = info;
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit();
   StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput;
   string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
   reader.Close();
   if (output.Length == 0)
   {
       reader = p.StandardError;
       string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
       reader.Close();
       MessageBox.Show(error);
   }
   else
   {
       //Aquí validas que tipo de LocalDB esta instalado MSSQLLocaldb, v11.0.. yo solo tomo estos 2..
   }
   ```
2. Si no está, instalar LocalDB SqlLocalDB.MSI la ultima versión.
3. Crear tu base de datos mediante un script, igual las tablas, procedimientos, etc.